# How to SELECT distinct with MAX and return full table fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table:

```
id  name    empid   t_date              lesson          score
1   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-47-56 fire            100
2   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-49-44 back            100
4   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-51-22 machine_guard   100
6   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-52-28 machine_guard   25
8   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-53-23 lockout         100
9   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-54-01 fire            36
10  Jeremy  9845    2015-02-12 11-08-43 back            92
11  Jeremy  9845    2015-02-12 14-06-50 back            36
12  Jeremy  9845    2015-02-12 14-25-06 machine_guard   90
13  Jeremy  9845    2015-02-12 14-43-32 machine_guard   95
```

I need to distinct the name,lesson and also want the maximum value of score.

Result I want:

```
id  name    empid   t_date              lesson          score
1   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-47-56 fire            100
2   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-49-44 back            100
4   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-51-22 machine_guard   100
8   Allen   9527    2015-02-11 15-53-23 lockout         100
10  Jeremy  9845    2015-02-12 11-08-43 back            92
13  Jeremy  9845    2015-02-12 14-43-32 machine_guard   95
```

I've tried:
SQL:

```
SELECT distinct name,lesson,max(score) as scores from test
where t_date between '2015-02-11' and '2015-02-13'
group by name,lesson

name    lesson          scores
Allen   back            100
Allen   fire            100
Allen   lockout         100
Allen   machine_guard   100
Jeremy  back            92
Jeremy  machine_guard   95
```

I don't know how to add the t_date.. fields to the result.The full fields of the table.If there is same scores with same name and lesson, I want to choose the t_date which is the early one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the `MIN()` of `t_date` for as I observed on your desired result, you're getting the early date for each of `name` group by `lesson`.See below:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT name, 
      lesson,
      MAX(score) AS scores,
      MIN(t_date) AS t_date
 FROM test
WHERE t_date BETWEEN '2015-02-11' AND '2015-02-13'
GROUP BY name,lesson
```

You can use the below query to get your desired result:

```
SELECT 
      MIN(id) AS id,
      name,
      empid,
      MIN(t_date) AS t_date,
      lesson,
      MAX(score) AS score
 FROM test
WHERE t_date BETWEEN '2015-02-11' AND '2015-02-13'
GROUP BY name,empid,lesson
```

Comment: BETWEEN t_date between ??

Comment: If this is Access SQL, the criteria for dates must read: where t_date between #2015-02-11# and #2015-02-13#